# Combine slope info with Landsat for classification in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, landsat, slope

I wanted to add slope data as a band to filtered Landsat data.
I used `ee.Image.cat` to "merge" two images. I can see added band in a merged image, but when I perform the classification (which worked before adding slope data), I got error: `Property 'sr_atmos_opacity' of feature '1_0_0' is missing.`
Probably, I have to find another way how to add slope band to my data, but I can't figure out how to do that.

This is the classification that work (only Landsat, without slope): https://code.earthengine.google.com/bac39dc10202d7ca2e4ce37ed6b458c5

This script doesn't work (with slope):
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b216bd7b78925e44e306b9e051aa73b

Comment: Can you please provide here your code for users that do not have Google Account?

Comment: I thought that impossible to open shared gee  script without an account

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function `addBands` of the `ee.Image` object

I modified the working script.

```
// lines from 87 to 90

var median = dataset.median()
var withSlope = median.addBands(addSlope)
var clipped_dataset = withSlope.clip(table)
```

and added the slope band to `bands`

```
var bands = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','LSWI','NDVI','EVI','MSAVI2','b1']
```

Your accuracy has been improved to 0.87

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e73c46f16188d930bcc1c5b37d0708dd